# Cross-referencing tables generated by xtable

Tags: cross-referencing, r, knitr, xtable

I'd like to cross-reference a table that I generated with xtable in R. I cannot able to. Here is what I did:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Look at \ref{tab:mytable}.
<<echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
  library(xtable, car)
  print(xtable(x=mtcars[1:5,1:5]), label = "tab:mytable")
@
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Nice question HBat (complete, simple example). The only thing missing (I know, I'm picky) is that in general it is helpful to show what output you get. e.g. post your PDF or if you encountered an error show which error you get. "I cannot able to" does not describe the output that you got. Welcome to SE!

Comment: By the way, *in my opinion* `xtable` should give you a warning because you specified the `label` argument but no `caption` argument. I would normally submit a patch, but the `xtable` authors haven't been too responsive lately so I'm hesitant to spend the time to do so.

Comment: @scottkosty I didn't know that I can able to post pdf's. Next time I'll try to do that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Actually I post a screen shot because that way it's zoomed in. I'm not sure if you can post PDFs (sorry for the unclear wording of my message).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at your example, the table does not have a number. I assume you want to reference the table number, so first we must give the table a number. To do this, use the `caption` argument.

Second, when using xtable, you have to be careful with which arguments you want to give to `xtable` and which arguments to `print.xtable`. You are currently passing the `label` argument to `print.xtable` but if you look at `?print.xtable` there is no `label` argument.

Taking into account both of the above points gives us:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Look at \ref{tab:mytable}.
<<echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
  library(xtable, car)
  print(xtable(x=mtcars[1:5,1:5], caption = "example", label = "tab:mytable"))
@
\end{document}
```

The above code gives me the following output (note that you may have to run your `latex`/`pdflatex` command more than once):

[image]